# Xamarin load listview from listview

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hi I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise and develop with Prism.Unity.Forms and Xamarin.Forms.
In my ViewModel I retrive from webservice my data (see this figure)
[image: ViewModel with data]

I would like retrieve this data into my View into ListView, but I can not have access to ListaEstadoCuenta, I can show "polizaId" and "estado"
this is the information in "ListaEstadoCuenta"
[image]

In my view I have the ListView:
[image]

Please help me how to display data "ListaEstadoCuenta" list in the Labels, I hope your help

Comment: How do you want to show it? Also can you post your viewmodel?

Comment: You have one label, but multiple pieces of data in your sublist.  Which data do you want to display?

Comment: I want to display muy sublist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListaEstadoCuenta` is a List. This means you have to specify the item in the bindings of your Labels. E.g. for the first Item:

```xml
<ViewCell>
<!-- ... -->
    <Label Text="{Binding ListaEstadoCuenta[0].Comprobante}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding ListaEstadoCuenta[0].FechaDoc}" />
<!-- ... -->
</ViewCell>
```

If you want to show list items in one Label, you have to use Converters to combine the values:

**Value converter**

```cs
public class StringConcatenationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IEnumerable<EstadoCuentaDetalle>)
        {

            return string.Join(", ", ((IEnumerable<EstadoCuentaDetalle>)value).Select(x => x.Combrobante));
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Resource in your Page**

You have to adjust the local namespace `xmlns:local` to refer your assembly name.

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FormsTest;assembly=FormsTest">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:StringConcatenationConverter x:Key="concatConverter"></local:StringConcatenationConverter>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
```

**Binding**

```
<Label Text="{Binding ListaEstadoCuenta, Converter={x:StaticResource Key=concatConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Yes of course... That's what I've written in the **second** line. Please think about it. I have updated my answer to give you some more help.